# Checking the received fund on an address of an HD Wallet

Tags: bitcoind, api

I'm running a bitcoind on my web server now. I would like to generate deterministic address (HD Wallet) and then check how much coin being received on such address. I'm looking at the Server API and it's quoting that:

`getreceivedbyaddress <bitcoinaddress> [minconf=1]`
Returns the amount received by `<bitcoinaddress>` in transactions with at least `[minconf]` confirmations. It correctly handles the case where someone has sent to the address in multiple transactions. Keep in mind that addresses are only ever used for receiving transactions. Works only for addresses in the local wallet, external addresses will always show 0.

That's being say the address need to be present in the local wallet for the check to be effective? Since I'm generating deterministic address outside of the bitcoind active wallet, is it considered non-local? If yes, how can I know the received amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Core clients do not keep track of the balance of addresses that aren't yours.

To make sure that they do keep track of them, import the private keys into your wallet, and restart your Bitcoin client with the -rescan option.

That's what they mean by non-local.

Comment: Thanks. We have been using Blockchain.info to retrieve these information these days.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn That works too.